# boost python and templates

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have a piece of C++ code that I'm trying to wrap using boost python that looks roughly like this:

header file:

```
template<class CatalogClass, class MemberClass>
class MyIterator
{
    public:
        MyIterator(SomeOtherArg& arg);

    private:
        Blah<CatalogClass,MemberClass>* mIterator;
```

cpp file:

```
template<class CatalogClass, class MemberClass>
MyIterator<CatalogClass, MemberClass>::MyIterator(SomeOtherArg& arg)
{
    mIterator = new Blah<CatalogClass,MemberClass>(arg);
}
```

Boost cpp:

```
class_<MyIterator<CatalogClass,MemberClass>>("MyIterator", init<SomeOtherArg&>())
;
```

My reason for the parameterization is so that the MyIterator can be used by a variety of classes, and thus, I don't need to rewrite this iterator for every class that derives from CatalogClass/MemberClass.  However, I get an error on compilation/linking that says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: MyIterator<CatalogClass,MemberClass>::MyIterator(SomeOtherArg&): referenced from boost::python::objects::value_holder<MyIterator<CatalogClass, MemberClass> >::value_holder<boost::python::objects::reference_to_value<SomeOtherArg&> >(_object*, boost::python::objects::reference_to_value<SomeOtherArg&>) in Test.o
```

Where else is it expecting me to define this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that templated classes don't actually exist until you specialize the template, this means that unless you pre-specialize your iterator no symbols are exported, so nothing to link to.  You'd have to pre-specialize your iterator for every combination of types you plan on using and then separately expose each specialization to Python.

Another solution, is [type erasure](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/).  You'd need to modify your iterator to have a non-templated base class.  The portion of your class that requires templates would inherit from your non-templated base.  You'll then be able to wrap the base class, but templated stuff would be inaccessible in Python.

In general, I try to avoid templates in the public interface of any library I create for external consumption.  You can template all you want in your implementation, but your public interface has to produce actual linker symbols.